# How to change the visibility using Haskell webdriver

Tags: haskell, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have started using Haskell and to improve the adaptation to the language I want to develop an application to automate the submission of the information to an web site. I need to simulate a click using selenium webdriver. Unfortunately I am stuck in an error caused by the element I want to click not being visible. How do I change following div visibility using an haskell webdriver command:

```
div id="DynObject129" 
    style="left: 3px; top: 47px; z-index: 1000; cursor: auto; 
           background-color: rgb(241, 239, 226); border-radius: 5px;
           visibility: hidden; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;
           border-color: rgb(32, 107, 164); overflow: hidden; 
           position: absolute; width: 310px; height: 313px;"
```

The exception is throwed after the execution of the following command:

```
pageItem <- findElem (ById "DynObject129") 
click pageItem
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any explicit change-CSS stuff in the `webdriver` package so you'll have to use the swiss-army-knife they provide:

```hs
-- |An existential wrapper for any 'ToJSON' instance. This allows us to pass
-- parameters of many different types to Javascript code.
data JSArg = forall a. ToJSON a => JSArg a

instance ToJSON JSArg where
  toJSON (JSArg a) = toJSON a

{- |Inject a snippet of Javascript into the page for execution in the
context of the currently selected frame. The executed script is
assumed to be synchronous and the result of evaluating the script is
returned and converted to an instance of FromJSON.

The first parameter defines a sequence of arguments to pass to the javascript
function. Arguments of type Element will be converted to the
corresponding DOM element. Likewise, any elements in the script result
will be returned to the client as Elements.

The second parameter defines the script itself in the form of a
function body. The value returned by that function will be returned to
the client. The function will be invoked with the provided argument
list and the values may be accessed via the arguments object in the
order specified.
-}
executeJS :: (F.Foldable f, FromJSON a, WebDriver wd) => f JSArg -> Text -> wd a
executeJS a s = fromJSON' =<< getResult
  where
    getResult = doSessCommand methodPost "/execute" . pair ("args", "script") $ (F.toList a,s)
```

According to this documentation, the correct command is something like:

```hs
executeJS [JSArg pageItem] "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';"
```

This will, of course, fail in a couple other circumstances: most notably, when an element is made invisible by `display: none` rather than `visibility: hidden`; for the former you may need to inspect what the web page actually does with these elements, since there is a style-difference between `display: block` and `display: inline` and you don't necessarily know which one causes the link to display correctly.

Comment: Hi, considering that I have made findElement and passing the result to executeJS using pageitem  
    `executeJS [pageItem] "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';"`  
I am using GHCi, which throws me an error:  
    Couldn't match expected type JSArg' with actual type `Element  
The first parameter shouldn't convert the webdriver element to a DOM element and execute it sucessfully?  
Thanks

Comment: @PedroSobreiro Sorry, I screwed that up. Try `[JSArg pageItem]` rather than just `pageItem` there.